# Docker within PCF - unable to connect to rabbitmq via AMQP (spring cloud bus)

Tags: docker, spring-boot, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

I'm playing with Pivotal cloudfoundry and docker. At the moment, I have a spring boot app which is a config server client along with spring cloudbus. This works if I push to PCF directly using `cf push demo-application target/my-jar-file.jar`.

I'm now trying to package my app as a docker container and push it into PCF with `cf push demo2 -o rraghur/demo`. PCF creates a container and deploys it - but spring cloudbus doesn't work.
Spring configuration does work as I see the following in the logs

```
2016-11-30T22:23:58.771+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] 2016-11-30 16:53:58.770 INFO 12 --- [ main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: https://config-67936b3e-1626-46b6-8117-480654f34e49.local.pcfdev.io
2016-11-30T22:24:00.588+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] 2016-11-30 16:54:00.587 INFO 12 --- [ main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=demo-application, profiles=[production], label=null, version=45c09f139492055b3a023462c852b82ae0d396a4, state=null
```

However, my app seems to unable to connect to the bound rabbitmq insntance - exceptions like:

```
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:547) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1389) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] 2016-11-30 16:54:01.015 WARN 12 --- [ main] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin : Failed to declare exchange: Exchange [name=springCloudBus, type=topic, durable=true, autoDelete=false, internal=false, arguments={}], continuing...
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:306) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1370) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1346) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareExchange(RabbitAdmin.java:157) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder.declareExchange(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:457) [spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.1.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder.createProducerDestinationIfNecessary(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:336) [spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.1.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder.createProducerDestinationIfNecessary(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:85) [spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.1.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:98) [spring-cloud-stream-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.0.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:53) [spring-cloud-stream-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.0.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:148) [spring-cloud-stream-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.0.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.ChannelBindingService.bindProducer(ChannelBindingService.java:113) [spring-cloud-stream-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.0.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:208) [spring-cloud-stream-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.0.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:57) [spring-cloud-stream-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.0.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:24) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:47) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar!/:na]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:822) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar!/:na]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:736) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar!/:na]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:293) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-30T22:24:01.016+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] ... 37 common frames omitted
2016-11-30T22:24:01.051+05:30 [APP/0] [OUT] 2016-11-30 16:54:01.051 INFO 12 --- [ main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel : Channel 'demo-application:production:0.springCloudBusOutput' has 1 subscriber(s).
```

Given that all services are injected in PCF via `VCAP_SERVICES` my thinking was that there should be no difference in how services are resolved/bound whether apps are pushed via buildpacks or docker containers...Also, the `connection refused` indicates a networking issue - so is there something about docker containers that works differently in PCF?

**UPDATE**

I `cf ssh`ed into both versions and installed `amqp-utils`. Then did `echo $VCAP_SERVICES` followed by `amqp-spy` on the `springCloudBus` exchange which waits till I break. **still no idea why spring boot would throw connection refused!**

```
root@2udd2sffmip:~# echo $VCAP_APPLICATION                                                                                                                                       
{"limits":{"fds":16384,"mem":256,"disk":512},"application_name":"new-openjdk8","application_uris":["new-openjdk8.local.pcfdev.io"],"name":"new-openjdk8","space_name":"dev","spac
e_id":"87680353-58ca-4250-84d1-91d1955acee1","uris":["new-openjdk8.local.pcfdev.io"],"application_id":"9c1244b5-70a1-4275-8d0d-bf9b54958054","version":"9710aaf6-588f-41b8-964d-3
422c6fb525d","application_version":"9710aaf6-588f-41b8-964d-3422c6fb525d"}                                                                                                       
root@2udd2sffmip:~# echo $VCAP_SERVICES                                                                                                                                          
{"p-rabbitmq":[{ "credentials": { "http_api_uris": [ "https://13f80867-b5cb-4f36-a689-9c4215a79ef7:if4odk9jshcda7sn74vss8vlh0@rabbitmq-management.local.pcfdev.io/api/" ], "ssl":
 false, "dashboard_url": "https://rabbitmq-management.local.pcfdev.io/#/login/13f80867-b5cb-4f36-a689-9c4215a79ef7/if4odk9jshcda7sn74vss8vlh0", "password": "if4odk9jshcda7sn74vs
s8vlh0", "protocols": { "management": { "path": "/api/", "ssl": false, "hosts": [ "rabbitmq.local.pcfdev.io" ], "password": "if4odk9jshcda7sn74vss8vlh0", "username": "13f80867-b
5cb-4f36-a689-9c4215a79ef7", "port": 15672, "host": "rabbitmq.local.pcfdev.io", "uri": "http://13f80867-b5cb-4f36-a689-9c4215a79ef7:if4odk9jshcda7sn74vss8vlh0@rabbitmq.local.pcf
dev.io:15672/api/", "uris": [ "http://13f80867-b5cb-4f36-a689-9c4215a79ef7:if4odk9jshcda7sn74vss8vlh0@rabbitmq.local.pcfdev.io:15672/api/" ] }, "amqp": { "vhost": "2fb4345b-9268
-4865-8340-98e949067d8d", "username": "13f80867-b5cb-4f36-a689-9c4215a79ef7", "password": "if4odk9jshcda7sn74vss8vlh0", "port": 5672, "host": "rabbitmq.local.pcfdev.io", "hosts"
: [ "rabbitmq.local.pcfdev.io" ], "ssl": false, "uri": "amqp://13f80867-b5cb-4f36-a689-9c4215a79ef7:if4odk9jshcda7sn74vss8vlh0@rabbitmq.local.pcfdev.io:5672/2fb4345b-9268-4865-8
340-98e949067d8d", "uris": [ "amqp://13f80867-b5cb-4f36-a689-9c4215a79ef7:if4odk9jshcda7sn74vss8vlh0@rabbitmq.local.pcfdev.io:5672/2fb4345b-9268-4865-8340-98e949067d8d" ] } }, "
username": "13f80867-b5cb-4f36-a689-9c4215a79ef7", "hostname": "rabbitmq.local.pcfdev.io", "hostnames": [ "rabbitmq.local.pcfdev.io" ], "vhost": "2fb4345b-9268-4865-8340-98e9490
67d8d", "http_api_uri": "https://13f80867-b5cb-4f36-a689-9c4215a79ef7:if4odk9jshcda7sn74vss8vlh0@rabbitmq-management.local.pcfdev.io/api/", "uri": "amqp://13f80867-b5cb-4f36-a68
9-9c4215a79ef7:if4odk9jshcda7sn74vss8vlh0@rabbitmq.local.pcfdev.io/2fb4345b-9268-4865-8340-98e949067d8d", "uris": [ "amqp://13f80867-b5cb-4f36-a689-9c4215a79ef7:if4odk9jshcda7sn
74vss8vlh0@rabbitmq.local.pcfdev.io/2fb4345b-9268-4865-8340-98e949067d8d" ] }, "syslog_drain_url": null, "volume_mounts": [ ], "label": "p-rabbitmq", "provider": null, "plan": "
standard", "name": "rabbitmq", "tags": [ "rabbitmq", "messaging", "message-queue", "amqp", "stomp", "mqtt", "pivotal" ] }],"p-config-server":[{ "credentials": { "uri": "https://
config-67936b3e-1626-46b6-8117-480654f34e49.local.pcfdev.io", "client_secret": "qSB9z4tI0Vix", "client_id": "p-config-server-f5c46df9-08f0-4779-bac1-3e2096a5efd6", "access_token
_uri": "https://p-spring-cloud-services.uaa.local.pcfdev.io/oauth/token" }, "syslog_drain_url": null, "volume_mounts": [ ], "label": "p-config-server", "provider": null, "plan":
 "standard", "name": "config-server", "tags": [ "configuration", "spring-cloud" ] }]}                                                                                            
root@2udd2sffmip:~# /usr/local/bin/amqp-spy -H rabbitmq.local.pcfdev.io -u 13f80867-b5cb-4f36-a689-9c4215a79ef7 --password if4odk9jshcda7sn74vss8vlh0 -V 2fb4345b-9268-4865-8340 
-98e949067d8d springCloudBus                                                                                                                                                  
^Ccan't be called from trap context
```

Comment: Have you tried using `cf ssh` to debug further?

Comment: Managed to get `amqp-utils` running; added an update to the question.

Comment: Am facing a similar issue where the boot application in docker is unable to connect to rabbitmq .  If i take closer look into the logs during the app start up in PCF I see the  the auto-re-configuring of the  bean **org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory** does not happen. Hence when app tries to look up rabbitmq it would do so on localhost and hence leading to the above error.

Comment: Continuing from the above comment and for anyone in future ending up here - resolved this by checking the active profiles I had on spring boot application. In my case it was a typo that bought me to my knees **Cloud v/s cloud**

Comment: I am still facing same issue, I have added cloud profile too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Raghu from the logs you have post'ed out it seems the active profile does not seem to include 'cloud' ,  which is the key for re-configuration and binding up your app to rabbitmq service.

Comment: I am still facing same issue, I have added cloud profile too, its still trying to connect localhost